# Quering DataTable in LINQ with C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to querying In memory data table with `LINQ` and view the result on a `DataGridView`

The thing is some time I want to reuse this code(`LINQ`),then **I can't hard code column names as bellow**.because some times column size may be different,so then I want to write one by one LINQ quays for each search criteria.

```
var filter = (from myrow in rsTable.AsEnumerable()
             orderby myrow[0]
             where myrow.Field<string>(0).ToLower().Contains(search) || myrow.Field<string>(1).ToLower().Contains(search)
             select myrow).ToList().CopyToDataTable();
```

If there is a method to pass parameter as column names or any method to improve this part as a function or any solution for this part ?

sample Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleLambdaExp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
        }
        private DataTable GetDataTable() {
            string str = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = str;
            string query = "SELECT [Description] ,[Type] ,[Category] FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Sales].[SpecialOffer]";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];

        }
        private void DetailsFilter(string search)
        { 
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            DataTable rsTable = null;
            rsTable = GetDataTable();
            try
            {
                var filter = (from myrow in rsTable.AsEnumerable()
                              orderby myrow[0]
                              where myrow.Field<string>(0).ToLower().Contains(search) || myrow.Field<string>(1).ToLower().Contains(search)
                              select myrow).ToList().CopyToDataTable();

                if (filter.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = filter;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == String.Empty) { dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable(); }
            else
            {
                DetailsFilter(textBox1.Text.ToLower());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is Windows Form**

[image]

Comment: Did you check this? http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

Comment: Please, there a exactly zero reasons to use LINQ to filter a `DataTable` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to stop using LINQ for querying a `DataTable` and start using a [`DataView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataView%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and setting its [`RowFilter` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx)).

Then simply bind the `DataView` to your `DataGridView`. This also has the advantage that you don't need to create an entire new `DataTable` everytime the filter condition changes.

So your code could look like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   readonly DataTable _data;

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       // querying a database in a ctor is bad IMHO, but that's just example code
       // keep a reference to the data once loaded
       _data = GetDataTable();
       // bind the gridview to the default DataView instead of the DataTable
       dataGridView1.DataSource = _data.DefaultView;
   }

   private DataTable GetDataTable() {
        ...
   }

   private void DetailsFilter(string search, IEnumerable<string> columnNames)
   { 
       // create the filter with AND and LIKE
       var filterString = String.Join(" AND ", columnNames.Select(c => String.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", c, search)));
       _data.DefaultView.RowFilter = filterString;
       // since the grid is bound the DataView, you immediately see the result
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == String.Empty) 
       { 
           _data.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Emtpy;
       }
       else
       {
           // note how we can pass column names
           DetailsFilter(textBox1.Text.ToLower(), new []{"Description", "Category"});
       }
   }
}
```

Note how it's shorter and avoids querying the database multiple times.

As for sorting, simply the the [`Sort` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'`

`The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])'`

Comment: It seem's you're using .Net 3.5. Just convert the result of `columnNames.Select(...)` to an array by calling the `ToArray()` method: `var filterString = String.Join(" AND ", ccolumnNames.Select(...).ToArray())`

Comment: it's worked with `var filterString = String.Join(" AND ", ccolumnNames.Select(...).ToArray())`!